# Aligning code/Code margin in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So when I used to program in java I did it in Eclipse. Whenever my code had all the same margin I just had to select everything and press Ctrl+i.
Now I use Visual Studio Professional for programming in C++
The question is simple enough: How to properly set a margin to the lines of code so that it all looks well and I can easily tell what code belongs inside what brackets.

Thank you beforehand, and I hope this question is not closed. I tried searching for an answer, but found none.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Select what needs formatting and CTRL+K followed by CTRL+F.

Comment: This is saving my life. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Found in the [C++ Visual Studio 2010 Keybinding Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13189):

Select the code you want to format then:

<kbd>CTRL + K, F</kbd> or
<kbd>CTRL + E, F</kbd>

> Formats the current selection 
>   according to the indentation and 
>   code formatting settings specified on
>   the  Formatting pane under  Tools | 
>   Options | Text Editor | C/C++.

Answer (score 4):

You can always find out what the actual shortcut is and use it or customize it:

1. go to Tools -> Options.
2. expand Environment, select Keyboard
3. type 'Format' in the textbox labeled 'Show command containing:'
4. find the row that reads 'Edit.FormatDocument'
5. read the value in the 'Shortcuts for selected command:' dropdown

If you want to change it, use a new shortcut key in the 'Press shortcut keys' box, then click 'Assign'.